# where is to take some calculation in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want some table that value on database already calculated but in database not calculated.

My controller code...

```
public function data2()
{
    $data['row']=$this->std->getdata2();
    $this->load->view('konversi',$data);
}
```

My model code...

```
public function getdata2()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('tb_data');
    return $query->result();
}
```

My view code...

```
<?php
    $i=1;

    foreach ($row as $r)
    {
        $pendidikans = 'pendidikan';
        $fpendidikans = $pendidikans * 100;        

        echo "    <td>";
        echo "    $r->lulusan</td>";

        echo "    <td>";
        echo number_format((float)$r->$fpendidikans, 2, '.', '2' );
        echo "</td>";

        echo "    </tr>";

        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add fields of table `tb_data`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this(I think,this is what you are trying)
view

```
    <?php


            $i=1;
                foreach ($row as $r) {
// if pendidikan is columnname
    $pendidikans = $r->pendidikan;
    $fpendidikans=$pendidikans*100;     

?>
                     <td><?php echo $r->lulusan; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo number_format((float)$fpendidikans, 2,'.' ,'2' ); ?></td>



                    </tr>
    <?php
                          $i++;
                }

            ?>
```